# How can I display this overflowing table so that it stays within its parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if I am allowed to post a link to the webpage instead of the code, but I think it will be easier to see the problem in action, and I'm sure you all know how to view the code in the browser's debugger...

https://redditstatsbot.com/

When you select a short table, everything is fine. But when you select a huge table, the table overflows out of the div and I lose the footer. How can I keep everything stationary and just scroll through the table instead of scrolling down on the web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the table height like this and then apply overflow: scroll

```
.table-div {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px); 
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

For the demo, I've used 300px. You can get the height of select-div, search-div, and footer and subtract the value from 100vh.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not stated your problem correctly but I understood your point. The tablet is not going out of the parent div but expanding itself to its content height.

Bind the height of the table which has div id="output-table" to a fixed height for example height: 55vh; according to your own need. And then give tbody a CSS property overflow: scroll;

This will fix your problem. You can play around with these CSS properties if you want something else but of the same problem. play with height and overflow properties.